# CSS3 Arrow inheriting the parent color in the :after

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the same background color in the `:after` in a line Arrow but I can't seem to figure out how to get it working. I need it in pure CSS3.

Here is what I have CSS3:

```
.arrowup:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 8px 7px;
    border-color: "I WANT THE YELLOW HERE NON STATICALY" transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 8px;

}
.arrowup:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 8px 7px;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 7px;

}
.backgr{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

as seen here the background-color is yellow and I would like the white in the border-color of the `:after` to contain that yellow of the background without statically putting it there.

HTML:

```
<div class="backgr">
   <div class="arrowup"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88n1z2zn/)

Comment: Don't go changing the meanings of your questions without updating the code

Comment: i updated my text to make it more clear what i mean, i'd like an inherit on the border-color but if i litterally put `inherit` it will be black and it needs to be the `background-color` of the class `.backgr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

declare the color in the backgr element :

```
backgr{
 //your other stuff...
--bg-color: yellow;
background-color: var(--bg-color); //added for clarity
}
```

and then use it with var(--bg-color) in the border-attribute of your arrow:

```
arrowup:after{
//your other stuff
border-color: var(--bg-color) transparent;
}
```

now, when you change the variable in your backgr elem it also changes the color inside the arrow.
(and if i'm not mistaken you could also access the variable via js)

Comment: you're welcome! though you should check if it's supported in your [target browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the white is not the background, it is the border you have.

So you need some to use some jQuery/JS as below to do it.

What this does is pulls the colour from the `.backgr` then adds a new css rule to `.arrowup:after` with that colour.

```js
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.arrowup:after', 'border-color: ' + $(".backgr").css('backgroundColor') + ' transparent!important;');
```

```css
.arrowup:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 8px 7px;
  border-color: #FFF transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 8px;
}

.arrowup:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 8px 7px;
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7px;
}

.backgr {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="backgr">
  <div class="arrowup"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already put it 'staticaly':

```
.arrowup:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 8px 7px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent; /* set it to yellow instead white */
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 8px;

}
```

You have to put it explicitly. Otherwise you won't get the triangle, you gonna get rectangle I guess.

Answer (score -1):

```css
        .arrowup:after {
    content: '^';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    height: 13px;
    top: 8px;
    transform: scale(2,1);
}
       
        .backgr{
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          background-color:yellow;
          position:relative;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="backgr">
       <div class="arrowup"></div>
    </div>
```

i tryied this if only arrow is what you want.